# Protecting executable in Mac OS

Tags: macos, cocoa, reverse-engineering

There are several executable protector in Windows platform which protect exe against reverse engineering such as ASProtect, PESpin, ...
How can I do it in MacOS? What is equivalent programs?
thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simular post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84324/how-to-protect-mac-os-x-software-from-cracking) that might be usefull.

rhinovirus recomends [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/) and millenomi recomends looking at [AquaticPrime](http://www.aquaticmac.com/)

Comment: Thanks. I read that post, it seems there are not real exe protector on Mac. (upx is compressor and AquaticPrime is licence generator and ...)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at 
http://morpher.com/ and [http://arxan.com/](http://arxan.com)

Comment: Thanks. Yes; both morpher and arxan are protector. morpher is also a compiler which is compatible only with gcc (I use c++ builder and delphi), arxan might be useful (more study is needed as regards has no demo version).